# Rails 4 collection_select from another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My model has the following (relevant) declartions:

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :placements, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :clients, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :clients, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :placements, allow_destroy: true
end

class Placement < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :client, through: :campaign
  belongs_to :campaign
  validates_presence_of :hashtags_instagram, :hashtags_twitter, :sms, :url, :channel
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :campaign
  belongs_to :placement

  validates_presence_of :client_name
end
```

So effectively, campaigns have many placements and clients. Placements have exactly one client, and are associated with exactly one campaign (or at least should be, I'm still not sure I did that correctly).

So in my placement form, I want it to display a dropdown menu of all of the clients belonging to the placement's campaign (not all campaigns). If it is a new placement, it should display "Please Select or similar", otherwise, it should display the client belonging to that placement.

I can't seem to get the :prompt option to work though. It never actually displays a Please Select, just the first client in the list. I was attempting to use this to get it to work:

Oddly, if I change prompt to include_blank, it does actually show the blank item (although it still selects the first client in the list, not the blank item).

When I tried some things, I tried the code:

```
 = f.collection_select(:placement_id, @placement.client.all.to_a, :id, :client_name, {:prompt => true}, class: "newdropdown-menu", id: "newdropdown")
```

And got the error message:

```
Could not find the source association(s) :client or :client in model Campaign. Try 'has_many :client, :through => :campaign, :source => <name>'. Is it one of :user, :placements, :clients, or :photo?
```

If I change the collection select to read:

```
= f.collection_select(:campaign_id, @placement.campaign.clients.all.to_a, :id, :client_name, {:prompt => true}, class: "newdropdown-menu", id: "newdropdown")
```

Then it runs, but does not actually display the prompt, just the list.

Changing @placement to placement does not seem to have any effect (which seems odd).

I don't want to change it to has_many, since placements should have exactly one client. How should I proceed? I tried messing with :source, but it doesn't seem to relate to my problem.

Comment: To start with, your association is `clients`, not `client`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place you html options in a hash:

```
f.collection_select(:campaign_id, @placement.campaign.clients.all, :id, :client_name, {:prompt => true}, {class: "newdropdown-menu", id: "newdropdown"})
```

Documentation available here:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select

Comment: I added the line:
      = f.collection_select(:campaign_id, @placement.campaign.clients.all, :id, :client_name, {:prompt => true}, {class: "newdropdown-menu", id: "newdropdown"})
as you suggested, but the behavior is exactly the same, it simply displays the list of clients, no "Please Select".

Comment: Oh okay, I misunderstood what you are trying to achieve, for that you would use include_blank: 'Please Select', so try this: f.collection_select(:campaign_id, @placement.campaign.clients.all, :id, :client_name, {include_blank: 'Please Select'}, {class: "newdropdown-menu", id: "newdropdown"})